# How to Read the Values From Input field inside td Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table and with in tds i had a text box

```
        <table class="table ratemanagement customtabl-bordered " id="rate_table">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="select_all()" class="check_all"></th>
             <th>From Days*</th>
             <th>To Days*</th>
             <th>Rent*</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <input class="case" type="checkbox">
             </td>
             <td class="v">
                <input id="rate_fromdays" class="form-control" name="fromdays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_todays" class="form-control" name="todays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_rent" class="form-control" name="rent" type="text">
             </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
             <td>
                <input class="case" type="checkbox">
             </td>
             <td class="v">
                <input id="rate_fromdays" class="form-control" name="fromdays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_todays" class="form-control" name="todays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_rent" class="form-control" name="rent" type="text">
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

i want to read the values from text box i tried

```
var values = {};
    $('.v input').each(function () {
        values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
```

and

```
$('input[name="fromdays"],[name="todays"],[name="rent"]').each(function () {
      var fromdays = $(this).val();
      alert(fromdays);
 });
```

I want to store the values in independent variables how do i do that ex all fromdays to firstvariable, all todays to second variable
how do i do that
Thanks

Comment: did you try `values.push($(this).val())`

Comment: What do you mean by independent variables? You have already created an object with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values in three different `arrays` by checking the `name` attribute of the `input` fields

```
var fromdays=new Array();
var todays=new Array();
var rent=new Array();
$('#rate_table input[type="text"]').each(function () {

    if($(this).attr('name')=="fromdays")
        fromdays.push($(this).val())

    if($(this).attr('name')=="todays")
        todays.push($(this).val())


    if($(this).attr('name')=="rent")
        rent.push($(this).val())

 });
```

[JsFiddle](http://tps://jsfiddle.net/dbdm87k1/2/)

Comment: Memon Itried your solution in every array all the 3 values are pushed (like fromdays has fromdays value,todaysvalue and rent)similarly for other two arrays also

Comment: @VenkataKrishnaReddy, the semi-colons after the if conditions where the problem, Please try now. have added the JsFiddle for reference

Comment: Thanks @Menon Works as expected

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = [];
    $('.v input').each(function () {
        values.push($(this).attr('name') = $(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click, iterate over the inputs and push their values in to the respective array:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#getVar', function() {
  var fromVar = [];
  var toVar = [];
  $('input[name=fromdays]').each(function() {
    fromVar.push($(this).val());
  });
  $('input[name=todays]').each(function() {
    toVar.push($(this).val());
  });
  alert('from: ' + fromVar + ' - to: ' + toVar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table ratemanagement customtabl-bordered " id="rate_table">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="select_all()" class="check_all"></th>
             <th>From Days*</th>
             <th>To Days*</th>
             <th>Rent*</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <input class="case" type="checkbox">
             </td>
             <td class="v">
                <input id="rate_fromdays" class="form-control" name="fromdays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_todays" class="form-control" name="todays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_rent" class="form-control" name="rent" type="text">
             </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
             <td>
                <input class="case" type="checkbox">
             </td>
             <td class="v">
                <input id="rate_fromdays" class="form-control" name="fromdays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_todays" class="form-control" name="todays" type="text">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input id="rate_rent" class="form-control" name="rent" type="text">
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
<button id="getVar">get variables</button>
```

Comment: Hi read each tr at once and get all the 2 values at once and store in json array. for eg var obj ={"fromdays":frmval,"todays":tovalue}